# Bootstrap form styling within modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have stuck with that for a while. I have a bunch of inputs within my modal window to create a season. But it is still not responsive (looks very bad on smaller screens).

Also those two buttons should be on the right side of the well. I tried things like "pull-right" class or "float left" and absolute position but then they are always cross the grey background. How can I fix that?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h3 class="pull-left">Seasons</h3>
    </div>

  <div class="modal-body" style="position: relative;">

    <div class="well">
        <div class="row" style="width: 80%; margin: 0;">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <span class="bold">Season name</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. High season">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="bold">From</span>
                <input type="date" style="font-size: 1.23rem;  display: inline-block;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div style="margin-left: 40px;">
                <span class="bold">To</span>
                <input type="date" style="font-size: 1.23rem;display: inline-block;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="position: absolute; right: 50px;">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="position: absolute; right: 20px;">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And code online goes here: http://www.bootply.com/ojhdwC4y4x#

Comment: what do you want  describe briefly in question  ? cross icon color change  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
             <h3 class="pull-left">Seasons</h3>
        </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="well">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Season name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It caused by `<span>` tag before `<input>` tag, I think. And let's try above code, using bootstrap input instead.
And result:
[image: Result here]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row" style="width: 80%; margin: 0;">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <span class="bold">Season name</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="bold">From</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="date">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="bold">To</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="date">
            </div>
        </div>
```

how about to change it default of bootstrap style?

Answer (score 1):

For the buttons you should use `modal-footer` like [described here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples). For the responsive code try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
             <h3 class="pull-left">Seasons</h3>
        </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="well">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <span class="bold">Season name</span>
              <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <span class="bold">From</span>
              <input type="date" style="font-size: 1.23rem;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <span class="bold">To</span>
              <input type="date" style="font-size: 1.23rem;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the modal component has limted size, and rows define some margins, but the native HTML 5 date will not fit on the well div nicely. So you can remove one column from "Season name". If you have a lot more elements I recomend divide them on multiple rows.